# Chromecast Custom Commands Not Working

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

Has anyone been able to add custom commands in the ChromeCast API?  I was successful in getting the TicTacToe example working with my developer ID as well as modified Protocol string (changed on both the client and server).

On the Android side, I have the existing "join" command which works, and I am adding a new "image" command:

```
public final void join(String name) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "join: " + name);
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        payload.put(KEY_COMMAND, KEY_JOIN);
        payload.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        sendMessage(payload);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create object to join a game", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send a join message", e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message Stream is not attached", e);
    }
}

public final void sendImage(String sURL) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendImage");
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        payload.put(KEY_COMMAND, KEY_IMAGE);
        payload.put(KEY_URL, sURL);
        sendMessage(payload);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Cannot create object to send image", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to send an image message", e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message Stream is not attached", e);
    }
}
```

If I call the join command, it works fine and I can see the message logged through the console in the browser.  But if I call the sendImage function, I get the following error:

"onEnded failed to connect channel: protocol error"

On the ChromeCast side, I can see when a valid command is received.  This function is getting called when I send the join command, but not when I send my custom "image" command.

```
/**
 * Message received event; determines event message and command, and
 * choose function to call based on them.
 * @param {event} event the event to be processed.
 */
onMessage: function(event) {
  console.log('***== pre onMessage ==***');
  var message = event.message;
  var channel = event.target;
  console.log('********onMessage********' + JSON.stringify(message));
  console.log('mPlayer1: ' + this.mPlayer1);
  console.log('mPlayer2: ' + this.mPlayer2);

  if (message.command == 'join') {
    this.onJoin(channel, message);
  } else if (message.command == 'leave') {
    this.onLeave(channel);
  } else if (message.command == 'move') {
    this.onMove(channel, message);
  } else if (message.command == 'queue_layout_request') {
    this.onQueueLayoutRequest(channel);
  } else if (message.command == 'image') {
    this.onImage(channel, message);
  } else if (message.command == 'video') {
    this.onVideo(channel, message);
  } else if (message.command == 'song') {
    this.onSong(channel, message);
  } else {
    cast.log.error('Invalid message command: ' + message.command);
  }
},
```

Any ideas?  Is there somewhere else where I need to define my custom commands?

EDITED:  also showing the onImage prototype:

```
/**
 * Image event: display an image
 * @param {cast.receiver.channel} channel the source of the move, which
 *     determines the player.
 * @param {Object|string} message contains the URL of the image
 */
onImage: function(channel, message) {
  console.log('****onImage: ' + JSON.stringify(message));

  //Hide video and show image 
  mVideo.style.visibility='hidden';
  mImage.style.visibility='visible';
  mImage.src = message.url;

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually means there was a JavaScript error in your receiver. Open Chrome on port 9222 at the IP address of your ChromeCast device and use the Chrome developer tools to debug the issue.

Did you declare a new function "onImage" in your receiver prototype for the message handler?

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at the chrome developer tools and see the console message there when it receives the join command.  When I originally had javascript errors, I would see them there in the console.  But now I don't see any new lines displayed when I send that image command - it's like it's not getting as far as the the javascript. And the code above is where I added the receiver prototype. Is there somewhere else you mean?

Comment: I suggest you restart the ChromeCast device. Some times it seems to cache older versions of the receiver. Also, enable "Preserve log upon navigation" in the developer tools settings just in case the receiver is closed for some reason.

Comment: I had restarted the ChromeCast device each time I made a change to the javascript code and it didn't help.  But after coming back a few hours later, I'm now seeing the "image" command actually being processed on the ChromeCast.  Maybe the caching is happening on Google servers?  I was thinking the ChromeCast device was getting it directly from my web server - but maybe not.  Thanks for the help!